# How do I make a function for mysql while

Tags: php, mysql, html, loops

MySQL

```
cat_id   cat_group    cat_name       cat_status
1        Vehicles     Cars           1
2        Vehicles     Motorcycles    1
3        Properties   Houses         1
4        Properties   Apartments     1
5        Electronics  Cameras        1
6        Electronics  Gadgets        1
```

HTML

```
  <select id="category" name="category">
    <optgroup label="Vehicles">
        <option value="1">Cars</option>
        <option value="2">Motorcycles</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Properties">
        <option value="3">Houses</option>
        <option value="4">Apartments</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Electronics">
        <option value="5">Cameras</option>
        <option value="6">Gadgets</option>
    </optgroup>    
  </select>
```

PHP

```
function cat_option()
{
  global $db;
}
```

Question

How do I create a php function for the loop of categories? So on the form I just call it by **`cat_option()`** and the results will looks like on **`HTML`**

Comment: We don't build it for you - what have you tried?

Comment: what kind of object is $db?  how do you connect to the database?

Comment: Without the optgroup yes. I'm stuck to group it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one single query, using multi-dimensional arrays:

```
<?php

$opts = array();
# select all active categories
$qr = mysql_query('SELECT cat_id, cat_group, cat_name FROM categories WHERE cat_status = 1 ORDER BY cat_id ASC');
# go through all results
while ($qa = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)) {
  $opts[$qa['cat_group']][$qa['cat_id']] = $qa['cat_name'];
  # e.g. $opts['Vehicles'][1] = 'Cars'
}

/*
# now your array looks like:
$opts = array(
  'Vehicles' => array(
    1 => 'Cars',
    2 => 'Motorcycles',
  ),
  'Properties' => array(
    3 => 'Houses',
    4 => 'Apartments',
  ),
  'Electronics' => array(
    5 => 'Cameras',
    6 => 'Gadgets',
  )
);
*/

?>
<!-- now output it -->
<select id="category" name="category">
<?php foreach (array('Vehicles', 'Properties', 'Electronics') as $label): ?>
  <optgroup label="<?php echo $label ?>">
  <?php foreach ($opts[$label] as $id => $name): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </optgroup>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks moeffju. How to get dynamic array for `foreach (array('Vehicles', 'Properties', 'Electronics') as $label` which it capture from `cat_group`

Comment: Just use `foreach ($opts as $label => $opt)` to iterate over all keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
$opts[$qa['cat_group']][$qa['cat_id']] = $qa['cat_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of elements in catalog will be small enough. You have to first get all the elements by using your SQL query.

Then you could sort those elements based on their values of cat_group. This way, items of similar category will be together. I am assuming you can apply sorting to object collection based on a particular attribute.

Then all you need to do is traverse the list and create new optgroup as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You probable want to use a `DISTINCT` query to get the different kind of `cat_group`'s first.  Then loop through those creating your `optgroup`'s.